# Android CountDownTimer as a Separate Class

Tags: java, android, class, timer, listener

I have created my own class that extends CountDownTimer. Since I use it often, I would like to have that class in its own java file.

However, I do not know of a way for the timer class to communicate with the class that created it.

Example: class A has a textView that displays some number of seconds. So, class A creates the timer.

- How can the onTick() method in CountDownTimer be told to update my
  textView with the current time?
- How can my class A know when the    timer has finished?

I'm sure it's a simple answer, I just know very little about threads, handlers, listeners, and whatever else you wizards are cooking up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be very similar using a regular countdown timer - just substitute your subclass for the regular timer instance. Also, pass the activity into the constructor so it can do whatever it needs to update the display.

E.g.

```
    mCountDownTimer = MyCountDownTimer(totalMsecs, callInterval, this).start();
```

Where MyCountownTime would have methods like this:

```
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            float fraction = millisUntilFinished / (float) totalMsecs;

                        // myActivity is passed in the constructor
            mMillisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;

            // progress bar is based on scale of 1 to 100;
            mActivity.progressBar.setProgress((int) (fraction * 100));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
                mMillisUntilFinished = 0;
            handleTimeOut();
        }
```

This assumes mActivity is passed in the constructor. I changed the code to assume the calling activity was passed as a variable in the timer constructor and set as a member of the timer class.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Now, when the timer finishes, how do I call a method that resides in the calling class?

Comment: Any ideas? I see that you can access variables of the activity that was passed in, but how would you call a method belonging to that activity?

Comment: @Allen Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Yeah.  In the constructor of MyCountDownTimer, instead of taking "Activity activity" as a parameter, I had the constructor take in an interface.  Something like TimerListener listener.  That interface is implemented by the activity, so that the count down timer can call any of the methods listed in the interface on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Pass variables in to it (like the `TextView` to update, or the entire activity)
2. Make the variables in the class using it static (timer class could access them directly)
3. Implement a callback mechanism